Longtable incorrectly adding an empty line at the start of the table
Here's my MWE:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{longtable}{lll}
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{Nonfiction} \\
    Key & Title & Author \\
    \endhead
    X & Y & ZZ \\
    X & Y & ZZ \\
    X & Y & ZZ
  \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}

Here's what it produces:

Notice the extra empty line after "Key..." and before the table entries, which I'd like to remove.
It turns out that if I change nearly anything (switch from memoir to article, comment out \setotherlanguages, remove \multicolumn), the problem goes away:

Of course, none of those is a real solution.
I have had no luck diagnosing the problem or discovering a workaround (aside from mangling the appearance of the document). Any assistance is appreciated.

Can you compile with lualatex instead of xelatex?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It would be nontrivial for me to switch to lualatex.

@DavidCarlisle If I compile the above example with lualatex, I don't get a blank row.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz well that's weird (also if you remove polyglossia and use pdflatex there is no blank row) hmm xetex must be adding a whatsit somewhere

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I deleted the initial comment to you as it seemed to have been er less than 100% accurate:-)

@DavidCarlisle Clearly one should blame xelatex for not fixing the users errors of error-free packages :P

good plan @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
